# addPanel() causes second plot in markdown

Tags: r, plot, knitr

I'm using R 3.4.3 and the latest knitr to create a markdown document. I created a time series plot with moving average in an ordinary R script like this:

```
plot(xts.qty_ordered.by_day, col = 'red', main = 'Qty Ordered by Day')
addPanel(rollmean, k=20, on=1, col = 'blue')
```

and it gives me the time series with the moving average superimposed. When I put it in the Rmd document and knit it, however, the output contains two plots: the first is the time series alone, and the second is the time series with the moving average superimposed. How can I make knitr R not double up the output like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to wrap the first plot within `invisible` in your Rmd document.

For example:

````
```{r}
library(xts);
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

invisible(plot(sample.xts[,"Close"]));
addPanel(rollmean, k = 20, on = 1, col = "blue");
```
````

Knitting produces:

[image]